# Android Button image proportion

Tags: android, imagebutton

Created two buttons with same image(.png) and different button texts. Problem is one button got right proportion that is according to the source image and another got oval in shape. The source image is full circle in shape.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button3);
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button3);
                button.setText("Count");
                button1.setText("reset");
```

Here on the app one button drawn in alright, the second one got oval in shape. Both buttons should be equal in size and shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the `WRAP_CONTENT` inside your Button layout to a value like 100dp.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="100dp" 
android:layout_height="100dp"       
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_marginBottom="77dp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="34dp" 
android:minHeight="64dip" 
android:text="@string/button_count" />
```